# codeigniter pass a id

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am using codeigniter and I am trying to pass an ID but don't succeed.

Here is the controller:

```
function resend_messages() {
    if($this->input->post('send')) {
        if(!$this->input->post('text')) {
            $data['output'] = 'Please Write a message';
        }
        else {
            $this->load->model('site_model');
            $product = $this->site_model->resend($this->input->post('id'));
            $insert = array(
                'sender' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                'receiver' => $product->sender,
                'content' => $this->input->post('text')
            );
            $this->db->insert('messages',$insert);
            $data['output'] = 'The message send successfully';
            //redirect('site/my_message');
        }
        $this->load->view('resend_message',$data);
    }

}
```

Here is the view:

```
foreach($product as $row) {
            print "<li><b>From:</b>{$row['receiver']}</li>
                <li><b>To:</b>{$row['sender']}</li>
                <li><b>Content:</b>{$row['content']}</li>
                <li><b>Date:</b>{$row['date']}</li>";
            print form_open('site/resend_messages');
            print $row['id'];
            print form_hidden('id', $row['id']);
            print form_submit('send', 'Resend message');
            print form_close();
            print "<hr />";
        }
```

And here is the model:

```
function resend($id) {
    $results = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id))->result();
    return $results;
}
```

So I would like some help.

Comment: Calling $this->input->post() inside your view  should be throwing an error...

Comment: From the form hidden.
Look at the current view.

Comment: You're using print form_open('site/resend_messages?act=' . $row['id'] . ''); to access your URL param. Do you have this enabled in config.php? The standard convention for CI would be 'site/resend_messages/'.$row['id']  and then accessing that parameter through the controller method, resend_messages($id). Still checking your code for more issues.

Comment: I am very sorry, don't look at the "?act = $row['id']", I forgot to delete it.
I am especially about the form hidden, and whey its not working..?

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually passing your product to your view. I'm not sure what your error reporting is set to, nor can I see the rest of your form, so I don't know why you're not seeing something complaining about $product not existing in the first place. In any case, your controller needs to at least do the following:

```
$data['product'] = $product;
```

I also noticed this:

```
$this->db->insert('messages',$insert);
```

I've heard disagreements on this from some folks, but you really shouldn't be accessing your DB directly from your controllers.